# Multiple ggplots on one page using a for loop and grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot multiple variable correlation plots on one page - but the points aren't being plotted correctly when I use a for loop. They are fine if I create each plot individually.

I have a dataframe called sig_df with the variable names, intercept and slope of the regression line, and the p-value of the correlation:

```
> sig_df
                 x                 y  intercept     slope      p_value
1 Share.incentives     User.profiles -0.1667891 0.5826598 0.0003577163
2 Share.incentives       Translation  2.2689199 0.4790595 0.0005928465
3      Translation  User.interaction  1.4696970 0.5757576 0.0008921255
```

and also a master dataframe with the x and y values of each variable, for a sample of 26

```
> master
   Share.incentives User.profiles Translation User.interaction
1                 5             4           5                5
2                 4             1           3                4
3                 6             4           5                5
4                 6             4           4                4
5                 4             1           5                3
..              ...           ...         ...              ...
```

I've used a for loop to look at every row in sig_df, look up the variable names in master and make a correlation plot. I have stored these plots in a list, then use grid.arrange to plot them on a page - the ablines are plotting correctly but the points on every plot are the same as the final plot in my list!
When I don't use a for loop, this doesn't happen. 
Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

```
plot_list<- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(sig_df)){
  y <- (sig_df$y[[i]])
  x <- (sig_df$x[[i]])
  slope <- (sig_df$slope[[i]])
  intercept <- (sig_df$intercept[i])
  plot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(data=master, aes(get(x), get(y))) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=slope, intercept=intercept) 

}

do.call(grid.arrange, c(plot_list, ncol=4))
```

Thanks,
KP

Comment: I've now overcome this issue by selecting the chosen columns in sig_df by avoiding the use of 'get':  `df <- select(master, get(x), get(y))  
  colnames(df)<- c('x','y')  plot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=slope, intercept=intercept) `

Comment: that's the correct approach; `get()` is generally best avoided, and definitely not recommended within a ggplot. Note that you can simplify the grid.arrange step with `grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, ncol=4)`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem. Here's my solution: change the `mapping` parameter to `aes_string()` in funtion ggplot

```
  plot_list[[i]] <- ggplot(data=master, aes_string(get(x), get(y))) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=slope, intercept=intercept)
```

Hope this helps.