# Multiple plots on one page using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

I have 12 plots generated by a loop and I want to plot them with 3 rows and 2 columns on one page (2 pages in total). I know how to do it in R

```
pdf("1.pdf")
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
for (i in 1:12) {
  x <- 1:10
  y <- 2*x + rnorm(x)
  plot(x, y)
}
dev.off()
```

But how to do this using `ggplot`?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
for (i in 1:12) {
  x <- 1:10
  y <- 2*x + rnorm(x)
  qplot(x, y)
}
```

I think I have to use `grid.arrange` but need some help on that. Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) is useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `cowplot` package that allows more flexibility than just using a naked `grid.arrange`.

This works - albeit a bit inelegantly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
lg <- list()
for (i in 1:12) {
  x <- 1:10
  y <- 2*x + rnorm(x)
  lg[[i]] <- qplot(x, y)
}
grid.arrange(lg[[1]],lg[[2]],lg[[3]],lg[[4]],lg[[5]],lg[[6]],nrow=3,ncol=2)
grid.arrange(lg[[7]],lg[[8]],lg[[9]],lg[[10]],lg[[11]],lg[[12]],nrow=3,ncol=2)
```

Another more elegant but somewhat obtuse way to do the `grid.arrange` is the following (thanks to Axeman and beetroot - note the comments).

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(lg[1:6], nrow = 3))
do.call(grid.arrange, c(lg[7:12], nrow = 3))
```

or this:

```
grid.arrange(grobs = lg[1:6], ncol=2)
grid.arrange(grobs = lg[7:12], ncol=2)
```

They all result in this - (think two of these - they look the same anyway):

[image]

Comment: You could do `do.call(grid.arrange, c(lg[1:6], nrow = 3))` and `do.call(grid.arrange, c(lg[7:12], nrow = 3))`

Comment: s. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461259/multiple-ggplots-on-one-page-using-a-for-loop-and-grid-arrange) about grid.arrange using a list: `grid.arrange(grobs = lg[1:6], ncol=2)`

Comment: I am also thinking he might like `cowplot` better.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Axeman and beetroot. Was surprised I got this in there, it hung around for 26 minutes before I noticed it. :)  I will add those as comments as I think the way it is is more didactic.

Answer (score 2):

`marrangeGrob` is a convenient wrapper for multiple pages,

```
marrangeGrob(lg, ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

or you can call `grid.arrange()` explicitly twice,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = lg[1:6], ncol=2)
grid.arrange(grobs = lg[7:12], ncol=2)
```