# ggplot and grob arrangement

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have 3 ggplots (g1,g2,g3) and would like to shows them arranged so that g1 is larger and inbetween the other 2.

```
g1 =ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1 ,y =1), aes(x = x, y = 1))+geom_point()
g2 = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1 ,y =1), aes(x = x, y = 1))+geom_point()
g3 = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1 ,y =1), aes(x = x, y = 1))+geom_point()
library(grid)
lay <- rbind(c(2,1,1,1,3),
             c(2,1,1,1,3))
gs = grobTree( ggplotGrob(g1), ggplotGrob(g2), ggplotGrob(g3)  )

grid.arrange(grobs = gs, layout_matrix = lay)
```

I was looking here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html  but  I get an error.  Any idea about the proper syntax?

```
Error in gtable_add_grob(gt, grobs, t = positions$t, b = positions$b,  : 
  Not all inputs have either length 1 or same length same as 'grobs'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504741/multiple-plots-on-one-page-using-ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never use the `grobTree` function but replace it with a list and it works

```
gs = list(ggplotGrob(g1), ggplotGrob(g2), ggplotGrob(g3))
grid.arrange(grobs = gs, layout_matrix = lay)
```

this is the result, as you want I think
[image]

Comment: For separate plots: `grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, widths=c(1,3,1))`.  Or, if the plots are already in a list (for example, `gs=list(g1,g2,g3)`): `grid.arrange(grobs=gs, widths=c(1,3,1))`.

Comment: @eipi10 i wast sure if i had to us the ggplotGrob in the list but i guess not