# How to show multiple charts in single window

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout

I have 4 different charts but unable to show all charts in single window.

tried using layout function, i guess going wrong somewhere

```
#VPC = ggplot(VP,aes(VP$Final.Source,fill = VP$City)) + geom_bar()
#AVPC = ggplot(AVP,aes(AVP$Final.Source,fill = AVP$City)) + geom_bar()
#BA3C = ggplot(BA3,aes(BA3$Final.Source,fill = BA3$City)) + geom_bar()
#BA2C = ggplot(BA2,aes(BA2$Final.Source,fill = BA2$City)) + geom_bar()
```

I want to view 4 Ghaphs in single window by 2X2 matrix

Comment: layout only works with base graphics. It's not compatible with grid graphics such as ggplot2. Use the gridExtra package.

Comment: Thanks Roland for info, i have installed gridExtra and its working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple plots on one page using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504741/multiple-plots-on-one-page-using-ggplot)

Comment: I used similar geom_bar for all 4, however with different criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve becoming a fan of the package called [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) which makes it ridiculously easy to combine plots of different types.